# Change size of an array by an arraylist

Tags: java, arrays

One of the main Charucteristic of the Array is immutability(Size of the array cant be changed) but while i was practicing i found myself in this case :

---

We have an Array with specific size

```
String[] strArr = new String[1];
```

And ArrayList with Objects

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("Alex");
list.add("Ali");
list.add("Alll");
```

So when we try to convert the list to an array and assign it to strArr , like this

```
strArr =  list.toArray(strArr);
        for(String str : strArr ) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
```

It works without a problem even if the size of the array doesnt equal the size of the list

---

So I JUST WANT TO KNOW HOW THIS IS POSSIBLE , WHEN THE SIZE OF THE ARRAY CANT BE CHANGED ?

Comment: Fix your CAPS LOCK key.

Answer (score 4):

## New array allocated

`strArray` first *references to a String array of size 1*, when you do `strArr =  list.toArray(strArr);`, you *change the reference of `strArray` to a different array*. So you are not changing the array size, you are only changing to which array now `strArrays` refers to.

Possibly you assume that `list.toArral(strArr)` modifies `strArr` but that's not the case, as you can read at the java documentation. It reads:

*"If the list fits in the specified array, it is returned therein. Otherwise, a new array is allocated with the runtime type of the specified array and the size of this list"*

The important section for your case, is where the documentation says: "Otherwise, a new array is allocated", so, no array resize is done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```java
strArr = list.subList(0, strArr.length).toArray(strArr);
```

Basicaly, the `List#subList(fromIndex, toIndex)` creates a new List with the elements starting in the `fromIndex` up to `toIndex` (self-explaintory)

You can read more about in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-

Answer (score 0):

It changes the reference to a new object. You can check this by calling: `System.out.println(strAttr)` immediately after you first assign the variable and then again after you call `strArr =  list.toArray(strArr);`